# Cursor moving to each corner

Tags: laptop, mouse, touchpad

My cursor moves on its own either to the bottom left end below start or to the diagonal opposite end.
My Pc (e7440) is a Dell running with windows 10.mouse is dell touchpad and wired logitech lazer mouse

Causes( Likely)

- New online battery( working but not brand battery so could be bulkier than normal)
- Game installed( two days after installation)
- Virus
- Corrupt driver
- driver software.

Fixes tried-( failed )

- Restarted computer
- Uninstalled game
- Unplugged mouse , tried another working wired mouse
- control panel> mouse > pointer option> precision pointer un checked.
- uninstalled mouse driver and restarted
- updated driver ( failed as its didnt find new update mostly.)
- cleaning the top of the touch pad.
- Antivirus is active but could find nothing there.
- Switched on and off internet.
- Became a caveman and often banged the two empty sides next of the touch pad when it dares to moves, it works 20% no 10% of the time or it gives up command to its owner.( It maybe the battery is bulkier than battery case/slot and it pushes against the touchpad from underneath on either side and might stop if I give it a a bang?)
  {Yes, I know that's not how laptops work but its absolutely frustrating

I'm not computer savvy or anything. I just tried solutions off the internet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and uninstalling the Dell Touchpad software solved it for me